# AngularJs pass promise response as argument to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I ran into a small dilemma. In this angularJs app (1.3.7v) I fetch requirements as well as user belongings from the server and perform some front-end validation. Which looks something like this:

```
validationFunction = function(userId){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    Promise.all([
      requirementService.requirementApi.requirements.getAll().$promise,
      userBelongingsService.userBelongingsApi.getAll(userId).$promise
    ]).then(function(requirements,belongings){
      console.log(requirements, belongings);
      resolve(isValid(requirements,  belongings));
    }).catch(function (err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

For reference I also tried

```
validationFunction = function(userId){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    requirementService.requirementApi.requirements.getAll().$promise.then(function(requirements) {
      return [requirements, userBelongingsService.userBelongingsApi.getAll(userId)];
    }).then(function(requirements,belongings){
      console.log(requirements, belongings);
      resolve(isValid(requirements,  belongings));
    }).catch(function (err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

The promises are async and so they only get resolved later. But if used with .then() it should wait until they are resolved (rejected or resolved). Although in both methods the promises are resolve(at some time) at the moment when they are passed to the function they are not. And so the function fails saying that they are undefined. So what is the other way or am I missing something? :)

Comment: the success callback in `.then` accepts a single argument ... in the case of Promise.all, this argument will be an array of resolved values

Comment: in es2015 (maybe es2016) - you can `.then(function([requirements,belongings]){` to get what you want

Comment: not sure what the `resolve(isValid(requirements,  belongings));` is meant to do, but perhaps you may just want to `return isValid(requirements,  belongings);` - it's not clear from the code you posted as there's no wayof knowing what the `resolve` function even is

Comment: I included the wrapper this time :)

Comment: your `validationFunction` doesn't return anything - perhaps you need to `return new Promise ...` - then read the other comments

Comment: Again sorry for the mistake :) did not copy it properly :)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 1):

your code can be simplified to

```
validationFunction = function(userId){
    return Promise.all([
        requirementService.requirementApi.requirements.getAll().$promise,
        userBelongingsService.userBelongingsApi.getAll(userId).$promise
    ]).then(function([requirements,belongings]){
        console.log(requirements, belongings);
        return isValid(requirements,  belongings);
    });
};
```

However, that contains some es2015+ specifics

so, in less modern JS

```
validationFunction = function(userId){
    return Promise.all([
        requirementService.requirementApi.requirements.getAll().$promise,
        userBelongingsService.userBelongingsApi.getAll(userId).$promise
    ]).then(function(results){
        console.log(results[0], results[1]);
        return isValid(results[0], results[1]);
    });
};
```

> edit: sorry, I missed a ) in the above code originally

To expand on the answer a little (got distracted with the real world) - Firstly, as @Bergi pointed out, Avoid the [Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! - as you are dealing with functions that return a promise (`Promise.all`, `....getAll().$promise`, `....getAll(userId).$promise`) there's no need to wrap all that in a `new Promise`

Secondly, the onfulfilled callback of `.then` is called with a single argument, the resolved value. In the case of `Promise.all`, this is an array of resovled values, in the same order as they appear in the `Promise.all` argument. That's why the ES2015+ version can use the ([a, b]) form for the function argument (sorry, I can't recall or find the "name" for this form). It's important to note that if either one of those Promises in the Promise.all array are rejected, Promise.all rejects with the rejected value of the (first) rejected promise (that's a lot of rejection in that sentence!)

You can also remove the .catch portion of your code, as the error handling can (and should) be done by the calling code to your function

```
validationFunction(someUserId)
.then(function(result) {
     // this will be the value of isValid(requirements,  belongings)
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // do some error handling here
});
```

and finally, in it's most ES2015+ form (that I can think of)

```
validationFunction = userId => Promise.all([
    requirementService.requirementApi.requirements.getAll().$promise,
    userBelongingsService.userBelongingsApi.getAll(userId).$promise
]).then(([requirements, belongings]) => isValid(requirements, belongings));
```

Comment: s/can/should/ :-)

Comment: true - should - but that sounds arrogant :p